# How to use two relationship i18n yaml file to show well in one form with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, yaml

I am using Rails 4.

I have two models:

app/models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_items, foreign_key: :product_id, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_items

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

app/models/product_item.rb

```
class ProductItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  validates :description, presence: true
end
```

And two i18n yaml files:

config/locales/products.ja.yml

```
ja:

  activerecord:
    attributes:

      product:
        name: '名前'
```

config/locales/product_items.ja.yml

```
ja:

  activerecord:
    attributes:

      product_item:
        description: '説明'
```

I want to save the two relationship data to database in one form:

app/views/products/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(product, url: path) do |f| %>
  <% if f.object.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <ul>
         <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :product_items do |item_form| %>
    <%= item_form.label :description %>
    <%= item_form.text_field :description %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

If the `name` or the `description` data are not been filled in the form, The errors will been shown.
But only the product data can be changed to Japanese, such as:

```
名前を入力してください。
```

- Means: Input name, please.

The product_item data was showed:

```
Product_items descriptionを入力してください。
```

- Means: Input description, please.

Why the second relationship model not been change to the right i18n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look [at the doc](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

> In the event you need to access nested attributes within a given
>   model, you should nest these under model/attribute at the model level
>   of your translation file:

In your case you should localize under `product/product_items`:

```
ja: 
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      product/product_items:
        description: "説明"
```

Comment: Thank you. I have did it. I can get `説明` by `Product.human_attribute_name('product_item.description)`. But it also showed `Product_items descriptionを入力してください。` in the form even I restarted rails application.

Comment: @s-cho-m I've created a project and it works. You probably misspelled something.

Comment: @s-cho-m you probably wrote `product/product_item` instead of  `product/product_items`. You should be checking for `Product.human_attribute_name('product_items.description')`

Comment: @dimakura Yes. You are right. My mistake:-) Thank you very much for your kindly help!